# How disable maintenance mode from files in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I don't have ssh access to one of my website. I have only FTP details . so how i can disable Mode using FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable magento maintenance mode by rename or delete of maintenance.flag file from var folder.